# For Loop Runtime Problem, only runs one time

Tags: java, arrays, loops, copy, helper

For some reason my Loop does go through the first loop run and ignores the rest of the array and always uses the Same Values.
My Console Test-Code:

`I-Counter: 0
Run-String: | || 
Beginnung Counter: 0
Char: |
IF: 1
Space: 
ELSE: 2
Beginnung Counter: 2
Char: |
IF: 3
Beginnung Counter: 3
Char: |
IF: 4
Space: 
ELSE: 5
Temporary: 8
I-Counter: 1
Run-String:   |||
Temporary: 8
I-Counter: 2
Run-String:   |||
Temporary: 8
I-Counter: 3
Run-String:  || |
Temporary: 8
I-Counter: 4
Run-String:  | ||
Temporary: 8
I-Counter: 5
Run-String:  || |
Temporary: 8
Falscher Code`

 I don't really see my mistake.

It goes trough both loops and then prints "Falscher Code", but the expected value is 
"24118".

What could be the reason for this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LinearCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "| || |  ||||  |||| || || | ||| || ||"; //Richtige PLZ
    System.out.println(calc(s));

}

public static String calc(String s) {
    String result = "";
    String wrong = "Falscher Code";
    int test = 0; //modulo-check
    int temp = 0; //temporär
    int t = 0; //counter for Checking Array
    int Counter = 0; // Counter for the Final Array
    int [] finalArray = new int[s.length()];


    String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\G.{6})");
    for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
      parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, 5);
    }

    int [] check = {0,1,2,4,7}; //Checking Array

    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("I-Counter: " + i);
        String run = parts[i];
        System.out.println("Run-String: " + run);
        for(int j=0; j < run.length(); j++) {
            if(!(run.charAt(j)== ' ')) {
                System.out.println("Beginnung Counter: " + t);
                t++;
                System.out.println("Char: " + run.charAt(j));
                System.out.println("IF: " + t);
            }else {
                if(t<check.length) {
                    temp += check[t];
                    t++;
                    System.out.println("Space: ");
                    System.out.println("ELSE: " + t);
                }else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Temporary: " + temp);
        if(temp == 11) { temp = 0;}

        finalArray[Counter] = temp;
        Counter++;
    }
    finalArray = Arrays.copyOf(finalArray, Counter);
    for(int i = 0; i < finalArray.length-1; i++) {
        test += finalArray[i];
    }
    test = (10-(test%10));
    if(test == finalArray[finalArray.length-1]) {
        for(int i = finalArray.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
            result += finalArray[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    return wrong;
}
```

}

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to use a *debugger*, especially how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Debugger in Eclipse does not work with JRE 13.0.1 for some reason

Comment: @Kirby_Sike downgrade to JDK 11 (you cannot use JRE to develop), your code doesn't use any JDK 13 feature.

Comment: Cant find JDK 11 for MacOS

Comment: what output do you expect

Comment: 24118 as a String

Comment: nevermind i am hell a blind...used the wrong variable for the check